# Manipulating identities

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, algebraic-geometry

I'm having some trouble deriving certain identities. If

$$S(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i)$$

then how can I write

$$\frac{1}{S(z)}\frac{d^2S}{dz^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z-z_i}\sum_{j\neq i}^n\frac{2}{z_i-z_j}$$

and
$$ \frac{1}{S(z)}\frac{dS}{dz}= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z-z_i} $$

Truth be told, I'm having some trouble writing the derivative of $S(z)$ in a neat, compact form.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** for the second:
$${\frac {{
\frac {d}{dz}}S \left( z \right) }{S \left( z \right) }}={\frac {d}{dz}}\ln  \left( S \left( z \right)  \right) $$

**Hint A** for the first:
$${\frac {{\frac {d^{2}}{d{z}^{2}}}S \left( z \right) }{S \left( z
 \right) }}={\frac {d^{2}}{d{z}^{2}}}\ln  \left( S \left( z \right) 
 \right) + \left( {\frac {d}{dz}}\ln  \left( S \left( z \right) 
 \right)  \right) ^{2}$$

**Hint B** for the first:

$${\frac {1}{ \left( z-z_{{i}} \right)  \left( z-z_{{j}} \right) }}={
\frac {1}{ \left( z_{{i}}-z_{{j}} \right)  \left( z-z_{{i}} \right) }
}+{\frac {1}{ \left( z_{{j}}-z_{{i}} \right)  \left( z-z_{{j}}
 \right) }}$$
Where the identities hold for any differentiable function (proof: chain rule).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac { dS } { dz} =\sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n\Pi_{j\neq i}(z-z_j)$

So $ \frac { 1 } {S ( z)}\frac { dS } { dz}=\sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n\Pi_{j\neq i}(z-z_j)/(\Pi_{i=1}^n(z-z_j))=\sum _ { i = 1 } ^ n\frac { 1 } {z - z_i}$

Now can you do the second derivative?